# How to add an object in a Firestore Array

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

General context: I've got a firestore list that has **PastInventoryItem**s, each of which has an array called **countedquantity**.

```
data class Material(
var type: String = "",
var material: String = "",
var size: String = "",
var description: String = "",
var unit: String = "",
var quantity: String = "0",
var actualquantity: String = "0") : FireStoreData()
```

Here's the Model class for the PastInventoryItem object

```
data class PastInventoryItem(
var username: String = "",
var date: String = "",
var countedquantity: ArrayList<Material> = arrayListOf()) : FireStoreData()
```

And when the PastInventoryItem is stored, provided I have the document ID, I'd like to add a Material on the countedquantity array saved in Firestore. All my attempts ended up overwriting the originally saved countedquantity, even when I'm using SetOptions.merge().

```
db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("ManageID",
            GlobalObject.FIRESTORE_ID))
            .collection("pastInventories")
            .document(documentID)
            .set(pastInventoryItem, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                Toast.makeText(materialDialog.getContext(), "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Toast.makeText(materialDialog.getContext(), "FAILURE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you need to update a single `Material` object inside the `countedquantity` array? If so, have checked [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) out?

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to show how `pastInventoryItem` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `set(..., SetOptions.merge())`, Firestore takes all values from the first argument and replaces the values in the database with them. Since you're passing a `PastInventoryItem` with all three fields, all three fields in the database are replaced.

---

If you want to replace a single field in the database, pass a **map** with a single field, or a field name and a value, as shown in the documentation on [updating a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java_16). For example, to update only the `countedquantity` field:

```
Map updates = new HashMap();
updates.put("countedquantity", /* your value here */);
db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("ManageID",
            GlobalObject.FIRESTORE_ID))
            .collection("pastInventories")
            .document(documentID)
            .set(updates, SetOptions.merge())
```

Now this code will update only the `countedquantity` field, but it will still replace that entire field.

---

If you want to *add* an item to the `countedquantity` array, use the `array-union` operation that is mentioned in the documentation on [updating items in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array). For example, to add the `pastInventoryItem` item to the array:

```
Map updates = new HashMap();
updates.put("countedquantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion());
db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("ManageID",
            GlobalObject.FIRESTORE_ID))
            .collection("pastInventories")
            .document(documentID)
            .set(updates, SetOptions.merge(pastInventoryItem))
```

Note that the item will only be added if there is no exact same item in the array already. Similarly: you can remove an item (if you know its entire value) with `array-remove`.

---

If you want any other type of mutation of the array, you will most likely have to perform the operation in steps:

1. Read the document from the database and get the current value from the array field.
2. Update the array in your application code.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

And given that you're modifying a document based on its current value, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for this.